# Gitlab-shell check failed 302 unable to clone/push/pull

Tags: api, http-status-code-302, gitlab

A lot of people have ask this question but it was 2 month ago with another gitlab version,

I'm using gitlab 5.2 in a fresh debian 7.0 serveur
everything looks Okay on the website but when I run /home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/check I've got this error :

```
Check GitLab API access: FAILED. code: 302

Check directories and files: 
    /home/git/repositories: OK
    /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys: OK:
```

I'm running on a custum ssh port but I'm able to connect.
When pushing I've got this error:

```
git push -vu origin master       
Pushing to ssh://git@apps.ndd.fr:2232/Users/test.git
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Precious issue (he one 2 months ago in GitLab 5.0): https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3483

Comment: this issues doesn't correspond to my problem, I can open the url !

Comment: It was a simple note, for me, in order to reference the similar but old issue you mention in your question. This isn't supposed to be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've just got the same error and go look onto the code.
The thing I've found the gitlab_net module going for answer at #{host}/check (gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_net.rb)

host method is defined as "#{config.gitlab_url}/api/v3/internal", and at the same time config.gitlab_url defined in ./gitlab-shell/config.yml "Should end with a slash" (c) So my web server just returns 302 on a request to remove double slashes.

FYI: That fail is about API and not about web service. So it's non-critical in many cases anyway.

I think it's a minor bug in code and there is a close issue to this: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3483